Не работает MapObjectTapListener внутри полигона
Назначаю полигону MapObjectTapListener.
При нажатии внутри полигона MapObjectTapListener не отрабатывает.
Отрабатывает только при нажатии на границу полигона.

Это так и должно работать?
Я делаю наверняка что-то не так?
Как заставить работать MapObjectTapListener внутри полигона, а не только на его границах?


Пожалуйста, пришлите нам минимальный пример вашей ситуации. Вы можете выложить его проектом на GitHub, прикрепить к переписке в архиве или загрузить на Яндекс Диск и указать ссылку.

Пожалуйста, отметьте в официальной документации на fillColor влияние прозрачности на работу MapObjectTapListener. https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/72#issuecomment-469415973

Очень странные дела в яндексе.
В полигоне на веб странице (javascript map api) отрабатывает event click вне зависимости от прозрачности fillColor.
А в android mapkit sdk - если fillColor установить прозрачность равной нулю, то MapObjectTapListener перестает срабатывать. И нигде в документации про fillColor не написано "С прозранчным цветом MapObjectTapListener не работает".
И это уже много лет так. Зачем и почему? Чем веб страницы отличаются от нативных приложений? Почему в веб странице кликаются прозрачные врутри полигоны, а в нативных приложениях не кликаются?
https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/72#issuecomment-469415973

похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите
